# How to add a menu only in the QTreeWidgetItem after pressing the right click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

My goal is to add a menu by right clicking the children of the QTreeWidget. We had planned to add a widget to the items and schedule the event from there, but I don't know that will actually work.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QTreeWidget,QTreeWidgetItem,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):


    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        self.tree_widget = QTreeWidget()
        self.tree_widget.setHeaderHidden(True)

        child1 = QTreeWidgetItem(["child top level"])
        child2 = QTreeWidgetItem(["child"])

        child1.addChild(child2)
        self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItem(child1)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.tree_widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MyWidget()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a real [mre], what is `params`? setItemWidget requires 2 arguments but only put one of them which is also unknown

Comment: im sorry, "item_widget = QWidget()" and "self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(params)" do not go in this publication, I wanted to make another publication asking how to use that method and what its parameters were, params refers to the parameters necessary for this method to work

Comment: I don't know how to edit the post to remove those two lines